# Why is my JPA update (edit) option not working?

Tags: java, jpa, crud

I am trying to create a CRUD with JPA. Both the insert new record and delete record work. But once I go to update, which is the line ctrl.edit(cats) it returns error: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Could someone please review my code and advise if there is something I am missing? I have created entities and controllers with JPA.

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@page import="entities.Categories"%>
    <%@page import="controller.CategoriesJpaController"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>CATEGORIAS</title>
    
            <script>
               function cargar(id,nom,des)
               {
                    document.modalito.txtcatid.value = id; 
                    document.modalito.txtcatname.value = nom; 
                    document.modalito.txtcatdes.value = des;
                }
            </script>
    
        </head>
        <body>
            <%
                HttpSession sesion = request.getSession(); 
                //validar que solo si hay sesion activa pueda entrar
                //la unica sesion es usuario y nivel
                if(sesion.getAttribute("usuario")==null && sesion.getAttribute("nivel")==null)
                {
                    response.sendRedirect("../login/index_login.jsp");
                }
        
                if(sesion.getAttribute("usuario")!=null && sesion.getAttribute("nivel")!=null)
                {
                    String useruser = sesion.getAttribute("usuario").toString();
                    String nivel = sesion.getAttribute("nivel").toString();
            %>
    
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
        
            <hr>
            <p style="color:white; font-size: 20px;"> Bienvenido <%=useruser%> (Nivel: <%=nivel%>) |         <a style="color:white;" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index.jsp"> | Home | </a></p> 
            <hr>
    
            </nav>
    
            <%
                }
                response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
                response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); 
            %>
    
            <br><br>
            <h3 align="center">Formulario Categorias</h3>
            <hr>
    
            <button style="margin-left: 45%;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal">
                Ingresar Nuevo
                </button>
                <br><br>
        
                <pre align="center">CONTENIDO DE LA TABLA PRODUCTOS</pre>
                <br>
    
            <%
                List <Categories> ls; 
                CategoriesJpaController ctrl = new CategoriesJpaController(); 
                Categories cats = new Categories();
                ls = ctrl.findCategoriesEntities(); 
            
         
        if(request.getParameter("btnGuardar")!=null || request.getParameter("btnMod")!=null || request.getParameter("btnEliminar")!=null)
        {
            //guardar en un objeto producto lo del form
            cats.setCategoryID(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtcatid")));
            cats.setCategoryName(request.getParameter("txtcatname"));
            cats.setDescription(request.getParameter("txtcatdes")); 
        }
            
            
        
        if(request.getParameter("btnGuardar")!=null)
        {
            ctrl.create(cats);
            out.print("<script>alert('Exito al insertar');window.location.href = 'vCategoria.jsp';</script>");
            ls=ctrl.findCategoriesEntities();
        }
        else if(request.getParameter("btnMod")!=null)
        {                    
            ctrl.edit(cats);
            out.print("<script>alert('Exito al modificar');window.location.href = 'vCategoria.jsp';</script>");
            ls=ctrl.findCategoriesEntities();
        }
        else if(request.getParameter("btnEliminar")!=null)
        {                    
            ctrl.destroy(cats.getCategoryID());
            out.print("<script>alert('Exito al eliminar');window.location.href = 'vCategoria.jsp';</script>");
            ls=ctrl.findCategoriesEntities();
        }
                
    %>
    
    <div style="width: 700px; position: relative; margin-left: 27%;">
        <table border="1" class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">ID CATEGORIA</th>
                    <th class="text-center">NOMBRE CATEGORIA</th>
                    <th class="text-center">DESCRIPCIÓN</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <%
                    for(Categories c : ls)
                    {
                       
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= c.getCategoryID()%>
                        <a href="javascript:cargar('<%= c.getCategoryID() %>','<%= c.getCategoryName()%>','<%= c.getDescription() %>')">
                        <img src="../recursos/editar.jpg" width="25px" height="25px" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= c.getCategoryName() %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= c.getDescription() %></td>
                </tr>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

<!--Este es el formulario modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="miModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                                
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Formulario de Registro</h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <form action="vCategoria.jsp" method="POST" name="modalito">
                                    <input type="text" name="txtcatid" placeholder="ID Categoria" class="form-control"  /><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="txtcatname" placeholder="Nombre Categoria" class="form-control" /><br>
                                    <input type="text" name="txtcatdes" placeholder="Descripción" class="form-control" /><br>
                                    
                                    
                                    <input type="submit" name="btnGuardar" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar"/>
                                    <input type="submit" name="btnMod" class="btn btn-info" value="Modificar"/>
                                    <input type="submit" name="btnEliminar" class="btn btn-danger" value="Eliminar"/>
                                    <input type="hidden" value="nuevo" name="opcion" /><br>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Hasta aquí el modal-->
    
</body>
```

Comment: How could a `JasperException` possibly have anything to do with JPA?

Comment: @crizzis a very good point indeed. My bad, I missed to add and effectively mention that, when I see the log from Payara server it mentions my JPAController.

Comment: Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at controller.CategoriesJpaController.edit(CategoriesJpaController.java:97)
 at org.apache.jsp.vistas.vCategoria_jsp._jspService(vCategoria_jsp.java:155)

Comment: Found the answer here: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/104830 please not that answer is in Spanish. So in case it helps anyone, my case is that the List on the Entity was not initiate.

Comment: On the OneToMany, I just added the = newArrayList(Products); and that resolved it: 

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoryID")
    private List<Products> productsList = new ArrayList<Products>();

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, in order to post as Resolved, I found the answer here: es.stackoverflow.com/a/104830 it is in Spanish but it did help.

I simply initiated my OneToMany List on my Entity in question and that resolved it.

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoryID") private List<Products> productsList = new 
    ArrayList<Products>
```